# How to use regex for querying in Solr 4

Tags: regex, solr

I've reached the point of desperation, so I'm asking for help. I'm trying to query results from a Solr 4 engine using regex.

Let's asume the document I want to query is:

```
<str name="text">description: best company; name: roca mola</str>
```

And I want to query using this regex:

```
description:(.*)?company(.*)?;
```

I read in some [forums](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Use-Regex-in-the-Query-Phrase-td4015335.html) that using regex in Solr 4 was as easy as adding slashes, like:

```
localhost:8080/solr/q=text:/description\:(.*)?company(.*)?;/
```

but it isn't working. And this one doesn't work either:

```
localhost:8080/solr/q=text:/description(.*)?company(.*)?;/
```

I don't want a simple query like:

```
localhost:8080/solr/q=text:*company*
```

Since that would mismatch documents like:

```
<str name="text">description: my home; name: mother company"</str>
```

If I'm not clear please let me know.

Cheers from Chile :D

**NOTE**: I was using `text_general` fields on my scheme. As @arun pointed out, `string` fields can handle the type of regex I'm using.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of trying regex search on `text` field type, try it on a `string` field type, since your regex is spanning more than one word. (If your regex needs to match a single word, then you can use a `text` field.)

Also do [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of special characters just to make sure they are not the cause for the mismatches.

```
q=strfield:/description%3A(.*?)company(.*?)%3B.*/
```

**Update:**
Just tried it on a string field. The above regex works. It works even without the percent encoding too i.e.

```
q=strfield:/description:.*?company.*?;.*/
```

Comment: I see. I was using text_general fields, probably thats the reason my regex queries where not working.

Comment: I also wrote a post about Solr regex search:  http://1opensourcelover.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/solr-regex-tutorial/

Comment: One question is there possible to search by range on string field ? 
From word which start TO ends with specific char sequences

Comment: Can u give an example?