# Solr Webapp Regular Expression Search

Tags: java, regex, solr, lucene

I am following the Solr [quick start tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) and got the web app up and running. I know that Solr has a regular expression search functionality and I am having a hard time get it working.

[image]

So here, I have a field called MFR and I want to use regular expression to match values like AVAGO. However, it is giving me errors like cannot parse it correctly, then I tried to escape certain characters and all the following didn't work:

```
MFR:AV\[A\]GO
MFR:AV/[A/]GO
MFR:AV/[A/]GO
MFR:"AV\[A\]GO"
MFR:"AV/[A/]GO"
MFR:"AV[A]GO"
```

Now, I started to ask myself is the q parameter the right place where I can put regular expressions or I am not even in the ballpark.

I also [played](http://datafireball.com/2016/03/01/solr-build-unit-test/) with the TestRegexpQuery in Eclipse running the unit test and clearly, the query is a different type of query. How can I get regex working in the GUI?

Comment: Try `MFR:AV\\[A\\]GO`

Comment: It seems like you need to specify the field to search, like: `q=strfield:/MFR:AV\[A\]GO/`. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882188/how-to-use-regex-for-quering-in-solr-4

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry Sir. Doesn't work

Comment: Then, perhaps, if Karsten's answer does not work, try `MRF:/av%5Ba-x%5Dgo/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is how to use a RegExpQuery on [query screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Screen).

You already did use RegExpQuery in lucene.

As default solr using the [standard query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser). The standard query parser does support `RegexpQuery` but a RegExp have to start and end with the slash character `/` like `MRF:/AV[A-X]GO/` or `MRF:/av[a-x]go/`.

Be aware that a regular expression must match against the token in the inverted index and not against the original word.

E.g. for FieldType "text_general" a word `AVAGO` will become the token `avago`, so a regExpr with uppercase letters would not match.

You can test with the solr [analysis screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen) the way from a word (in real text) to the corresponding token in the index.

See also: [How to use regex for querying in Solr 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882188/how-to-use-regex-for-querying-in-solr-4)