# SOLR query trying to correlate to regular expression

Tags: regex, solr

I have to do a query with one criteria "customer name consists only of letters and _".  I did a lot of google searches, but I guess I do not know the correct string to search for an example of this query.

If it were a regular expression I would use something like "[a-zA-Z_]+" but I am not sure how to do that with SOLR.  I have a web interface to try it out on.
In my fq I have

**patient_lastname:"[a-zA-Z_]*"**,

which, as I figured, does not work.
so any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Try `q=strfield:/patient_lastname:"[a-zA-Z_]*"/`

Comment: Thanks.  That gives me:   "msg": "undefined field strfield",
    "code": 400       maybe I misunderstood which part to type in?

Comment: I was using google on strfield.  The first thing that came up looked like a good article explaining it.  When I clicked on it, I got that CYBOSS blocked.  This site contains child pornography.  What?  Why was it the first thing to come up with Google?  It was http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Difference-between-textfield-and-strfield-td3986916.html  I know it is maybe on a tangent from the item, but no I am curious.

Comment: The suggestion is from [How to use regex for querying in Solr 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882188/how-to-use-regex-for-querying-in-solr-4). If it does not work, I can't help more, sorry.

Comment: That is OK.  Thanks anyway Wiktor.

Comment: You have to use the actual field name first of all - i.e. `patient_lastname:/[a-zA-Z_]+/`.